# Current Logged in User Windows 2008 Server R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I just want to see my login info after I am logged in, including the domain.
Is there an area where I can see that on Windows Serer 2008 R2?

Comment: You might want to define "my login info" a bit more - my answer kinda just guessed at what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just type `whoami` on the command line.

Comment: that did it, thx

Comment: Good answer but there's no way to know if the domain listed is the local domain (computer) or AD domain, unless the OP knows what his computer name is. (which he probably does).

Comment: That's very true. If you really needed to, I'm sure you could write a vbs script and determine if you're logged on locally or on the domain with some WMI-fu.